# Exit Jupyter Notebook .ipynb cell based on a condition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

```
from sys import exit
import sys    
i=0
while i < 10:
   print(i)
   i=i+1
   if i==5:
      exit(0)

 print(' i do not want to print this')
```

Based on the above code snippet , I am looking to exit Jupyter Notebook cell.

Error I am getting is :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3275: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

I tried

```
sys.exit(0)
```

but still not able to exit the execution gracefully

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0
```

Comment: use `quit()` - `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

Comment: Why would you want to do so? `exit()` normally would kill the kernel, not just the cell. If you simply want to bypass some piece of code, you can put it under a boolean flag. Something like: `for i in range(10): i+=1, if i==5: flag= True` and then outside of `for` loop: `if not flag: print('this will be printed')`?

Comment: Introducing a flag variable is a good idea , I was trying to replicate the problem with a simple code snippet. As same code works in databricks